# how can I set GOP size to be a multiple of the input framerate?

Tags: ffmpeg

#### Question:

How can I set GOP size to be a multiple of the input framerate?

#### Context:

My ideal GOP size formula is `source_fps * 2`. My source's framerate can be either 30 or 60 fps so I'm unable to set a static value that works for both. Is there a variable that ffmpeg exposes that I can use?  I know you can get metadata about the source input when using the `-vf` option with variables like `iw` or `ih`. Is there a similar method for FPS?

Example command where GOP size and keyint_min is hardcoded:

```
ffmpeg -i <input> -keyint_min 120 -g 120 -f dash /path/to/out.mpd
```

Desired command where e GOP size and keyint_min are based on the source framerate:

```
ffmpeg -i <input> -keyint_min source_framerate * 2 -g source_framerate * 2 -f dash /path/to/out.mpd
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-g` only accepts frame intervals.

FFmpeg has a `-force_key_frames` option to force KFs at regular time intervals or as per more involved logic. See its entry in https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-Video-options

Add

```
-force_key_frames expr:gte(t,n_forced*2)
```

to force a keyframe every 2 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Gyan! Does `force_key_frames` replace the need for `-g` and `-keyint_min` entirely? I've been following this answer that suggests you need to use all three options. https://superuser.com/a/908325/909837